# $\frac{1 + 2 + ... + (1+p(k-1))}{(1+p(k-1))} = \frac{2 + p(k-1)}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{1 + 2 + ... + (1+p(k-1))}{(1+p(k-1))} = \frac{2 + p(k-1)}{2}$$

How do I get from left to right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1+2+ \cdots + (1+p(k-1)) = {1\over 2} (1+ (1+ p(k -1)) \times (1+p(k-1))$

Generally, $a +(a+d) + \cdots+ (a+(n-1)d) = {1\over 2} (a+ (a +(n-1)d)) \times (n-1)$. This formula was found by Gauss. (Add the first and the last term together and then the second and the last second...

Comment: doesnt equal to $\frac{2 + p(k-1)}{2}$?

Comment: U26467 gave you the sum for the numerator. Divide by the denominator and you will get the result you desire.